# Differences of scipy.spatial.KDTree in python 2.7 and 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a pandas dataframe containing a list of x,y coordinates and I am using scipy.spatial to find the nearest point in the dataframe given an additional point.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial as spatial

stops = pd.read_csv("stops.csv")
pt = x,y
points = np.array(zip(stops['stop_lat'],stops['stop_lon']))
nn = points[spatial.KDTree(points).query(pt)[1]]
```

Now, in python 2.7 this work perfectly. In python 3.5 I get the following error:

```
.../scipy/spatial/kdtree.py", line 231, in __init__
self.n, self.m = np.shape(self.data)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

In the docs I can't find anything useful.

Comment: What does `points` look like? In Python3, `zip()` returns a [`zip` iterator object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) rather than a list of tuples, so `points` is probably a 0-d object array containing a `zip` iterator in the second case.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the problem. I did list(zip(...)) and now it works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python3, `zip()` returns an [iterator object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) rather than a list of tuples. `points` will therefore be a 0-dimensional `np.object` array containing a `zip` iterator, rather than a 2D array of x, y coordinates.

You could construct a `list` from the iterator:

```
points = np.array(list(zip(stops['stop_lat'],stops['stop_lon'])))
```

However, a more elegant solution might be to avoid using `zip` altogether by indexing multiple columns of your dataframe:

```
points = stops[['stop_lat','stop_lon']].values
```